# Why can not create new product when i use EasyAdmin on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I install EasyAdmin Bundle for my backend web service, but when i want to create a new instance on the crud controller page, i got a error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmGiU.png)
There is my entities

```
/**
     * @var Tipoproducto
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tipoproducto", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idTipo", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $idtipo;

    /**
     * @var Precio
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Precio")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idPrecio", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $idprecio;
```

And there is my crud controller code

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
            TextField::new('nombre'),
            TextareaField::new('descripcion'),
            IntegerField::new('stock'),
            TextField::new('foto'),
            AssociationField::new('idtipo', 'Tipo'),
            AssociationField::new('idprecio', 'Precio'),
        ];
    }
```

I dont have idea why i got this error, i followed the offcial page to create my web service

I try to change on my entites because i saw some video, theres entites are diferent but it not work.

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO, the error seems to be about idtipo, it looks like you returned nothing, is your idtipo correct set when you submit ? If no, try to check if you allowed null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i get the solution for this question.
I need to override createEntity() metod to assign a value for my idtipo properties of the new producto. I nned to assign a instance of the entity TipoProducto to it.

```
public function createEntity(string $entityFqcn)
{
    $product = new Producto();
    $precio=new Precio();
    $tipo=new Tipoproducto();
    $precio=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Precio::class)->findOneBy(['id' => '1']);
    $product->setIdprecio($precio);
    $tipo=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Tipoproducto::class)->findOneBy(['id' => '1']);
    $product->setIdtipo($tipo);
    return $product;
}
```

Now my page can read this propiertes.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8wfB.png)